# EF6 - How do describe a Cascading Delete for 1:M with a shared child table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've got a 3 entities in my db context: People, Stores and Address. All the entities have an Id property that is their PK.

People have a 1:M to Addresses. the People Entity has a virtual List.
Stores have a 1:M to Addresses. the Store Entity has a virtual List.

The address table will hold addresses from both People and stores.

When I persist a people graph, all the addresses in the graph should get persisted with the people entity.

When I persist a store graph, all the addresses in the store graph should get persisted with the store entity.

When I delete a store, I want EF to delete all the addresses associated with it. 
When I delete a people entity, I want EF to delete all the addresses associated with it.

How can I set up these relationships using the Fluent API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.

in the mappers for Store and People, I set up an optional relationship with cascade delete:

```
  this.HasMany(x => x.Addresses)
                .WithOptional() 
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

This seems to be working, including the cascading deletes.